# WebEngineView getting text input focus

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtwebengine, qwebengineview

How can I detect focus on the text field (input) on the webpage displayed using QML WebEngineView?

I need this information to display/hide the virtual keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To getting text input focus on the webpage displayed via QML **WebEngineView** required is use **WebChannel** and run some js code on your webpage. You don't need to modify the page source.

**QML side:**

```
import QtWebEngine 1.5
import QtWebChannel 1.0
...
QtObject{
    id: someObject
    WebChannel.id: "backend"

    function showKeyboard() {
        console.log("Show the keyboard");
        inputEngine.showLiteralKeyboard = true
    }
    function hideKeyboard() {
        console.log("Hide the keyboard");
        inputEngine.hide()
    }
}

WebEngineView{
    id: webview
    url: "https://your-webpage.com/"
    anchors.fill: parent
    settings.javascriptEnabled: true
    webChannel: channel

    onLoadingChanged: {
        if(loadRequest.status === WebEngineView.LoadSucceededStatus){
            webview.runJavaScript(systemManager.qwebchannelSource())
            webview.runJavaScript("
                new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel){
                    var backend = channel.objects.backend;
                    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
                    var index;

                    for(index=0; index < inputs.length; index++)
                    {
                        inputs[index].onfocus = function(){
                            backend.showKeyboard()
                        };
                        inputs[index].onblur = function(){
                            backend.hideKeyboard()
                        }
                    }
                })")
        }
    }
}

WebChannel{
    id: channel
    registeredObjects: [someObject]
}
...
```

**systemmanager.cpp: Contains function to load and expose qwebchannel.js source:**

```
...
QString SystemManager::qwebchannelSource()
{
    QFile qwebchannelFile(":/qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js");     // Load the JS API from the resources
    if(!qwebchannelFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
        qDebug()<<"Couldn't load Qt's QWebChannel API!";
    }

    QString scriptSource = QString::fromLatin1(qwebchannelFile.readAll());
    qwebchannelFile.close();

    return scriptSource;
}
...
```

**systemManager.h Header part with exposing function:**

```
...
Q_INVOKABLE QString qwebchannelSource();
...
```

**NOTE:** The **SystemManager** object must be [exposed to QML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html#exposing-methods-including-qt-slots).